# How do I install my Eaton 5SC UPS on ubuntu server 20.04?

Tags: ups

This is what I did.

```
apt-get install nut
nano /etc/nut/ups.conf
```

I pasted this at the bottom

```
[eaton-5sc]
driver = usbhid-ups
port = auto
```

I started it up

```
upsdrvctl start
```

Then I got this response

```
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.41 (2.7.4)
USB communication driver 0.33
Using subdriver: MGE HID 1.40
```

How do I proceed to make the ups shutdown my server if there are a powerloss?